# cakephp 2.X Connection timed out on redirect on a live server

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a "register" page that accepts the username, password and confirm password data from the user. on my local machine it just redirects just fine. I think the problem is on php's max execution time but i've talked with my hosting's support and was told that the max execution time of the hosting company is not subject to be changed.

Here is my code. I don't think there is any problem with my code because it works fine with my local machine.

```
public function register($role = null){
    $this->reg_status();
    if($this->Auth->user()){
        return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'dashboard'));
    }

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {

        $this->User->create();
        $existing = $this->User->find('first', array(
        'conditions' => array('email' => $this->request->data['User']['email'])
        ));
        if($existing){
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Email is already used.'), 'default', array('class' => 'alert alert-danger'));
        } else{
            if($this->request->data['User']['password']==$this->request->data['User']['conf_password']){

                if($role){
                    $role = ($role == 'as_adviser') ? 'adviser' : 'client';
                    $this->request->data['User']['role'] = $role;
                }
                if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
                    $id = $this->User->getLastInsertId();
                    $this->sendMail($this->request->data['User']['email'], $id, 'verify');
                    return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'confirm_email', $id, urlencode(base64_encode($this->request->data['User']['email']))));
                } else {
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'), 'default', array('class' => 'alert alert-danger'));
                }
            } else{
                $this->Session->setFlash(__("Password did not match."), 'default', array('class' => 'alert alert-danger'));
            }
        }
    }

    $this->set('role', $role);
}
```

this is the error i am having on the live server.
[image]

i am currently out of clue because even if i turned "on" the debug on cakephp's config/core the error still seems vague.

edit
had to change Email config smtp settings. made sure they were correct and the error disappeared.

Comment: How is disabling the E-Mail sending functionality a reasonable solution to an E-Mail sending problem? Accepting such answers is not helpful for future readers.

Comment: my email config was the one at fault. had to change the config's smtp details.

Comment: Then please add that as your own answer, and accept it later on. The currently accepted answer is not a solution, and will only confuse people.

Comment: ok noted. will do

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->sendMail($this->request->data['User']['email'], $id, 'verify');
```

This line problem comment this line & check.

Answer (score 0):

had to change Email config smtp settings. made sure they were correct and the error disappeared